# How do I do a "NOT IN" query in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, database

This is my document:

```
{ 
    title:"Happy thanksgiving",
    body: "come over for dinner",
    blocked:[
       {user:333, name:'john'},
       {user:994, name:'jessica'},
       {user:11, name: 'matt'},
    ]
}
```

What is the query to find all documents that do not have user 11 in "blocked"?

Comment: You forgot a comma after "come over for dinner" :P

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use **$in** or **$nin** for "not in"

Example ...

```
> db.people.find({ crowd : { $nin: ["cool"] }});
```

I put a bunch more examples here: http://learnmongo.com/posts/being-part-of-the-in-crowd/

Comment: instead of "cool", how can I match an element inside a dictionary?

Comment: If you have just one element, you can also use $ne. If you are looking for an element inside a nested struct (instead of an array) you can check for the existence/nonexistence of the key. An example of this would be db.myCollection.find({'blockedPeople.george': {$exists: false}});

Comment: the link is dead x_X

Answer (score 47):

Since you are comparing against a single value, your example actually doesn't need a NOT IN operation. This is because Mongo will apply its search criteria to every element of an array subdocument. You can use the NOT EQUALS operator, $ne, to get what you want as it takes the value that cannot turn up in the search:

```
db.myCollection.find({'blocked.user': {$ne: 11}});
```

However if you have many things that it cannot equal, that is when you  would use the NOT IN operator, which is $nin. It takes an array of values that cannot turn up in the search:

```
db.myCollection.find({'blocked.user': {$nin: [11, 12, 13]}});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it also explains the difference between the two:
1. $ne is for "not equal"
2. $nin is for "not in"

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
db.stack.find({"blocked.user":{$nin:[11]}})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#op._S_nin

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $nin: [ 5, 15 ] } } )
```

> This query will
>   select all documents in the inventory collection where the qty field
>   value does not equal 5 nor 15. The selected documents will include
>   those documents that do not contain the qty field.
>
> If the field holds an array, then the $nin operator selects the
>   documents whose field holds an array with no element equal to a value
>   in the specified array (e.g. , , etc.).