# How to see removed records from mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I have an array with some `IDs` and I want to remove the records from mongo which does not have the ids from my array.

I used this code

**EDIT**

```
`> db.people.remove({ "_id" : { $nin: ["1","2","3"] }});`
```

**END EDIT**

I got inspired from here [How do I do a "NOT IN" query in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391643/how-do-i-do-a-not-in-query-in-mongo)

I need to see which records was removed. Is there a method to get there data from query directly?

I prefer to avoid the method in which I search for current data from mongo, and then see the difference between my array and the one from mongo.

I'm applying this to Symfony2, so if somebody has some suggestions, it would be awesome

Comment: The real question is *"Why should it matter to you?"*. Under what circumstances would it be any benefit to you to know which of the supplied values resulted in a match and subsequent removal and which were simply not found? There really should be no case. If you are trying to "synchronize" then remove all from once source and it should not matter if you don't actually match anything for removal from the other. If you must be so pedantic about this then loop the array of values and issue `.findAndModify()` while returning the original document. `null` means not found. But  never in bulk.

Comment: It matters because I want to keep track of the ones that were removed, but I don't want to make two different queries.

Answer (score 2):

`db.people.remove` doesn't return the removed documents, but it will return the number of removed documents so that you can check they were all removed successfully.

Here's a way you could do what you want, but it may or may not be right for your application:

1. Find the set of documents that you want to remove
2. Keep them in memory (i,e. store them as a list assigned to a variable)
3. Do the remove action
4. Check the number of removed documents to ensure success
5. If successful, display the documents from the variable

Alternatively you could use the findAndModify command http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/. This will return the removed document, but it only does one at a time, so you will need to do some kind of loop.

Comment: Sorry, I know that what I put on my question only searched for records and does not remove them. I tried to show an example of what I did (almost), so people understand what I want to do (my bad it was "find" and not "remove" in the post). I managed to remove the records that are not in my array of IDs.

You suggested to "Find the set of documents that you want to remove". Do you know what other method I can apply beside the one I said I want to avoid?

Comment: I didn't think that the method I suggested was exactly the one you wanted to avoid ... never mind though. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607487/how-to-get-removed-document-in-mongodb. I've edited my answer too

Comment: That link doesn't solve my problem: 'findAndModify' doesn't work for me. I don't know which are the values I need to be removed, so I cannot search and remove them. That is what I need to find: which values are removed after I run the query from my question. But thank you for your interest and help.

Comment: You can use $nin in findAndModify