# How can I efficiently delete many documents with certain criteria using reactive mongo template?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

The problem is that the following code takes much time to execute I have 50K documents in the collection and it takes 15 seconds to execute. The function takes epochTime and get the ones that are older than filteredDate. Then find and delete them.

```
public Mono<List<AuditLog>> archiveAuditLogs(long filteredEpochTime) {

        Query query = new Query();
        Date filteredDate = Date.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(filteredEpochTime));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("createdAt").lte(filteredDate));
        return this.mongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove(query, AuditLog.class).collectList();
        

     
}
```

How can I optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons for such bad performance, the collection size of 50K records (although I do not know the physical size of the collection) is not big at all.

Nevertheless, the request issued is quite simple. The things I can advice:

1. I assume you need deleted instances of the `AuditLog` since you are returning them. But in case you just need the number of removed records or some meta information about deletion, it may suffice to [just issue this query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html#remove(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,java.lang.Class)) instead of `findAllAndRemove()`. The problem is that `findAllAndRemove()` **actually triggers 2 queries - one to read all the data to be removed, and another to remove read records**. It certainly impacts your performance, but again, if this is a requirement, [I do not see a clear way out to return records after deletion in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842921/how-to-see-removed-records-from-mongo), just keep it in mind.
2. Enable [queries profiling](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) for some time. And then you can check what exactly took so much time per query basis. Maybe the [COLLSCAN](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/) impacts your performance and you need to add [some indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/). Maybe it is due to the master/slave network issues, I have faced that a couple of times in my livetime. So basically these are approaches unrelated to your code base.

Hope I have provided some guidance, have a nice day!