# Remove document from results if in different collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have assign, checkin and asset collections, when I go the the `/assign` page I run a query of:

```
Asset.find({"author.id":req.user.id}, function(err, allAsset) {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.locals.assets = allAsset; // Set the data in locals
          next();
        }
      });
```

To find all assets that the logged in user has. I want it so that if the `asset`is already assigned that it won't be available to assign again. A sample document from mongodb for an assigned asset is:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("59fb2cdb02b2a83502cd0df6"),
     "subuser" : "Kirbytech",
     "checkoutDate" : "2017-12-30",
     "notes" : "241361",
     "author" : { 
       "id" : ObjectId("59d7f98a77fcc221d6e3c93d"), 
       "email" : "joe@example.com.ca" 
     }, "asset" : {
       "id" : "59f7cde58a6f9b11e1cd07d9",
       "num" : 1005 
     },
     "__v" : 0 }
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391643/how-do-i-do-a-not-in-query-in-mongo) but it doesn't really help me much. I know I need to search for all documents where `asset.id` is found or not found (not sure which) then save those results to `res.locals.assets`.

I sure hope this makes sense. Please ask for clarification if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you query the Assign collection with the user_id and asset_id, if the return value is null, the asset has not been assigned.

I am assuming that the Assigned record is created when an asset is 'assigned' to the user.

```
Assign.find({}, function(err, assignedRecords){
 // this will be an array of all assigned assets
 let allAssignedAssets = assignedRecords.map((doc) =>doc.asset.id)
 // now get all the assets not in the above array
   Asset.find({id:{$nin: allAssignedAssets}}, function(err, allUnassignedAssets) {
     if(err){
      console.log(err);
     } else {
      res.locals.assets = allUnassignedAssets; // all unassigned assets
      next();
   }
 } 
})
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.